# How to pass model attributes between method inside controller Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

Good day folks.

I have couple methods inside controller I want to pass model attributes between them,
First method gets data from a database:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String resultHTML(@RequestParam String name, @ModelAttribute("fbosAttributes") FormBackingObjectSearch fbos,BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) throws Exception {

    model.addAttribute("findAttributes", educationWebService.fetchByNam(fbos.getName()));

return "search";
```

And another method have to get attributes witch was created from method above:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result.xls", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String resultXLS(@ModelAttribute("findAttributes") ArrayList<FormDate> mylists, Model model) throws Exception {  
    model.addAttribute("findAttributesNew", mylists);
    return "xlspage";
}
```

when I check for `mylists.size()` it shows/returns 0

Please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; if you're calling `resultXLS` *from* `resultHTML` just call it, but that sounds like a questionable design. You need to explain what you're trying to do with more precision.

Comment: Simply pass from one method to another Model Attributes which I got from resultHTML to resultXLS method.

Comment: It's just a method call--call it.

Comment: I don't understand Sir. Could you describe in more details?

Comment: Store the results of `fetchByNam`. Pass them in the call to `resultXLS`.

Comment: Sir how can I pass it, over request attributes(getAttributes(), setAttributes()) doesn't work I tried already.

Comment: Huh? If you're not making an actual request, and you're just calling the method directly from within the same Java request, just call the method. It's still not clear what you're trying to do, or why.

Comment: I'm trying to pass attributes which I got from method resultHTML to resultXLS. Why, because I want to use them to make excel file from model.

Comment: ... Store the results of `fetchByNam`. Pass them in your call to `resultXLS`. I don't understand the issue.

Comment: I don't understand store where how ass attribute? pass how? I would like to use request scope. how can I do this?

Comment: Using "request scope" makes no sense if you're calling from one Java method to another in the same request.

Answer (score 0):

You can add session attributes to your controller class by this annotation:

```
@SessionAttributes({"findAttributes"})
```

Comment: I can Sir. But it won't looks like good idea. I would like to use request attributes instead but how???

Comment: @UDS: If you don't want to use session attributes then you can organise cache from method call educationWebService.fetchByNam(fbos.getName()). Or call this method on both functions.

Comment: How to organise cach Sir?? Could you please help??

Comment: @UDS: Just store result on function call inside Map<String, ArrayList<FormDate>>. Where string is key for function call you can pass to model in first method and using it as GET attribute to call second function from web page.

Comment: I don't understand store where how ass attribute? pass how? I would like to use request scope. how can I do this?